# CheckBox Button On/Off state

Tags: html, angular

I am using Angular 6 for my project and have a single slider radio button in my code.

I have a function `switchClicked` which is responsible for handling certain events based on an ON/OFF state of this button.

Is there any way to pass an On/Off value of this button to my function.

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <label class="slider-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked (click)="switchClicked()">
    <span class="slider-slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `$event` from your method which will contain different properties including checked.

```
<div class="col-3">
  <label class="slider-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" checked (click)="switchClicked($event)">
    <span class="slider-slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
switchClicked(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.checked);
}
```

It will give you `checked` property of `srcElement` "true" or "false" depending on your ON/OFF state.

Comment: `event.currentTarget.checked`will give you true/false value

Comment: Thanks @AliShahbaz, In this case srcElement also carry the checked value... I found it good to use srcElement... Because sometimes it gives 'undefined' in currentTarget

Answer (score 1):

In HTML

```
 <div class="col-3">
      <label class="slider-switch">
        <input   type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="myCheckbox"  (ngModelChange)="switchClicked($event)">
        <span class="slider-slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

In TS

```
  myCheckbox: any = true;

  switchClicked(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Note: Without an event, you can take a checkbox value using myCheckbox property,  myCheckbox property will update using two-way data binding

To use ngMode and ngModelChange you have to import FormsModule in your module file from

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: use of ngModel is deprecated in angular 6

Comment: @DeepakSharma ngModel is deprecated in angular 6 with reactive form module, isn't it? with Template Driven forms it not depreciate.

Comment: thanks for correcting me, I was using reactive form module, so just wanted to warn others if they are using reactive models

Answer (score 0):

One nifty way to do this is to use Angular template variables, like this:

```
<div class="col-3">
  <label class="slider-switch">
    <input #myCheckbox type="checkbox" checked (click)="switchClicked(myCheckbox.checked)">
    <span class="slider-slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

And in  your Typescript:

```
switchClicked(clicked) {
    console.log(clicked);
}
```